# Rename multiple images in a folder using a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, dos, rename

I have a folder full of images which have a format filename.com_XXX_IMG_000.jpg.  The issue comes because the file name has a .com in it, it confuses the the software that I am using to upload it to a webspace.

I need to create a batch file that gets all the images in a folder and renames all of them from filename.com_XXX_IMG_000.jpg => filename_XXX_IMG_000.jpg.

Any help would be greatful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do it in a batch file:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=. tokens=1,2,3" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  set part=%%g

  if "!part:~0,3!"=="com" (
    set oldname=%%f.%%g.%%h
    set newname=%%f.!part:~4!.%%h
    echo "!oldname!" -^> "!newname!"
    ren "!oldname!" "!newname!"
  )

  endlocal
)
```

A few notes

- `for` loop variables are single letter, like this: `%f`
- in a batch file, the `%` must be escaped, so `%f` becomes `%%f`
- `delims=.` splits the filenames at the `.`, in your case into three parts
- `tokens=1,2,3` returns three variables containing the individual name parts (`%f`, `%g` and `%h`)
- `enabledelayedexpansion` switches on dynamic variable handling
- you can do string manipulation with variables: `%foo:~0,3%` returns the first three characters of `%foo%`.
- with delayed expansion enabled, you can access variables that change their values by using `!` instead of `%`
- the `>` must be escaped or `echo` won't print it, hence `^>`
- read some more on [String Manipulation in DOS](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: This works but removes the com but not the dot before filename.com_XXX => filename._XXX. How would you modify to remove the dot aswell?

Comment: @Chill If you actually read through my code and squint your eyes, you'll see it.

Comment: Found it set newname=%%f.!part:~4!.%%h => set newname=%%f!part:~4!.%%h Thanks for your help

Comment: How would you run another batch file after this function has been completed?

Comment: @Chill The same way you would start it from the command line.

Comment: How would you change the directory? Would you change the dir /b to something like C:\FILES\IMAGES\ ?

Answer (score 1):

read `HELP FOR` and try the following....

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  set fn=%%~na
  set fn=!fn:.com=!
  echo REN "%%a" "!fn!.jpg"
)
```

you need to *enable delayed expansion* because you need to expand a variable inside the for loop.

the loops iterates over all the jpg files in the current directory and for each file it extracts its filename using the `~n` syntax, and then it removes all the occurences of `.com` by replacing them with an empty string. Read `HELP SET`

after careful testing, remove the `echo` command

Comment: Thanks for your method, but I tried it and it didn't work. I have the batch file in the same folder as the images is that correct?